# How do I get directory depth in PowerShell 3.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to find out how far down the directory structure inside a working directory goes. If the layout is something like

```
Books\
Email\
Notes\
    Note 1.txt
    Note 2.txt
HW.docx
```

then it should return `1`, because the deepest items are `1` level below. But if it looks like

```
Books\
Photos\
Hello.c
```

then it should return `0`, because there is nothing deeper than the first level.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick in V3:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Name | Foreach {($_.ToCharArray() | 
    Where {$_ -eq '\'} | Measure).Count} | Measure -Maximum | Foreach Maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not as pretty, and arguably not as "Posh" as Keith's, but I suspect it might scale better.

```
$depth_ht = @{}
(cmd /c dir /ad /s) -replace '[^\\]','' |
 foreach {$depth_ht[$_]++}

 $max_depth = 
  $depth_ht.keys |
   sort length |
   select -last 1 |
   select -ExpandProperty length

 $root_depth =
  ($PWD -replace '[^\\]','').length

 ($max_depth -$root_depth)
```